# How can I get this .slideToggle method to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

When I use .slideToggle/.slideDown/.slideUp, no action takes place and I don't know how to make it so the navigation menu drops when #web is scrolled over. The navigation menu I'm referring to is the #webdsn-drop.

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
      <div id="nav-container">
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
        <a href="posters+flyers.html">Posters & Flyers</a>
        <a id="web" href="#">Website Design</a>

      </div>
  </div>
        <div id='webdsn-drop'>
            <div id="webdsn-content">
                <h2 id="webname">WEBSITE DESIGN<h2>
            </div>
        </div>  


  <div id="banner-container">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM<br>SAMPLE<h1> 
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Sample Lorem Ipsum Sample</h2>
  </div>

 <div id="thmbnl-container">  

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/workspace-banners_23-2147509206.jpg">
      <h1>Web Design</h1>
    </a> 
  </div>


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="posters+flyers.html">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/blue-company-poster_23-2147493194.jpg">
      <h1>Posters & Flyers</h1>
    </a>  
  </div> 


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wave-business-card-design_1017-4370.jpg">
      <h1>Business Cards</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-logo-template_23-2147490980.jpg">
      <h1>Logo Design</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  </div> 

  <h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>
  <div id="recent">
    <div id="recent-container">
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    /* border: solid;
    border-color: black; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

}

/*--------------Navigation Bar------------*/

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#nav-container h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;

}

#nav-container a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "calibri light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

#nav-container a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-container a:active {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

#nav-container h1:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#webdsn-drop{
    padding: 75px 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.95);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 9;
    display: none;
}

#webdsn-content{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#webname{
    color: black;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'calibri light';
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;  
}

/*--------------Banner------------*/

#banner-container {
    margin-top: 75px ;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 75px 0px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;

}

#banner-container h1 {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;

}

#banner-container h2 {
    width: 950px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

/*-----------Category Thumbnails---------*/

#thmbnl-container {
    width: 950px;   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.ctgrs-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container img {
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
}


.ctgrs-container h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


.ctgrs-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #727272;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;
}

/*----------Recent Projects----------*/

#recent-container {
    width: 950px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: ;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.thmbnl-recent {
    padding: 20px 13px 0px 13px;
    width: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.thmbnl-recent h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#recent-title {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    text-align: center;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.thmbnl-recent:hover {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.thmbnl-recent:active {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}


/*--------SLIDE IMAGE---------*/

#gallery-container {
    margin: 75px 0px 45px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
}

#slide-section {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;

}

#gallery-container h1{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

#imgrow {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').hover(function(){
        $('#webdsn-drop').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what I think you are looking for with proper movement of the dropdown.

Going off of [JB Lovo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837341/8161714) answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').hover(function(){
        $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown(500);
    },
    function(){
      $('#webdsn-drop').hover(function(){}, function(){$(this).slideUp(500);});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    /* border: solid;
    border-color: black; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

}

/*--------------Navigation Bar------------*/

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#nav-container h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;

}

#nav-container a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "calibri light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

#nav-container a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-container a:active {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

#nav-container h1:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#webdsn-drop{
    padding: 75px 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.95);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 9;
    display: none;
}

#webdsn-content{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#webname{
    color: black;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'calibri light';
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;  
}

/*--------------Banner------------*/

#banner-container {
    margin-top: 75px ;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 75px 0px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;

}

#banner-container h1 {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;

}

#banner-container h2 {
    width: 950px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

/*-----------Category Thumbnails---------*/

#thmbnl-container {
    width: 950px;   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.ctgrs-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container img {
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
}


.ctgrs-container h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


.ctgrs-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #727272;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;
}

/*----------Recent Projects----------*/

#recent-container {
    width: 950px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: ;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.thmbnl-recent {
    padding: 20px 13px 0px 13px;
    width: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.thmbnl-recent h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#recent-title {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    text-align: center;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.thmbnl-recent:hover {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.thmbnl-recent:active {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}


/*--------SLIDE IMAGE---------*/

#gallery-container {
    margin: 75px 0px 45px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
}

#slide-section {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;

}

#gallery-container h1{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

#imgrow {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
      <div id="nav-container">
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
        <a href="posters+flyers.html">Posters & Flyers</a>
        <a id="web" href="#">Website Design</a>

      </div>
  </div>
        <div id='webdsn-drop'>
            <div id="webdsn-content">
                <h2 id="webname">WEBSITE DESIGN</h2>
            </div>
        </div>  


  <div id="banner-container">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM<br>SAMPLE<h1> 
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Sample Lorem Ipsum Sample</h2>
  </div>

 <div id="thmbnl-container">  

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/workspace-banners_23-2147509206.jpg">
      <h1>Web Design</h1>
    </a> 
  </div>


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="posters+flyers.html">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/blue-company-poster_23-2147493194.jpg">
      <h1>Posters & Flyers</h1>
    </a>  
  </div> 


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wave-business-card-design_1017-4370.jpg">
      <h1>Business Cards</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-logo-template_23-2147490980.jpg">
      <h1>Logo Design</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  </div> 

  <h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>
  <div id="recent">
    <div id="recent-container">
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way for the slide down to disappear even when the mouse moves off of web design too becuase now it does disappear when you move off the area like it should but if you move your mouse off of the web design button it still says. This would be a major help have been looking for solution for hours!

Comment: @AbuN2286 There is, but this would most likely involve restructuring your HTML a decent amount. Typically navbars are done using lists (`<ul>` and `<li>`). Having dropdowns as child elements is what will give you the desired effect along with some minor JS/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close your `<h2 id="webname">WEBSITE DESIGN</h2>`

If you hover on Website design, the dropdown menu appears. Is that what you are looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').hover(function(){
        $('#webdsn-drop').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    /* border: solid;
    border-color: black; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

}

/*--------------Navigation Bar------------*/

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#nav-container h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;

}

#nav-container a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "calibri light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

#nav-container a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-container a:active {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

#nav-container h1:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#webdsn-drop{
    padding: 75px 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.95);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 9;
    display: none;
}

#webdsn-content{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#webname{
    color: black;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'calibri light';
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;  
}

/*--------------Banner------------*/

#banner-container {
    margin-top: 75px ;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 75px 0px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;

}

#banner-container h1 {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;

}

#banner-container h2 {
    width: 950px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

/*-----------Category Thumbnails---------*/

#thmbnl-container {
    width: 950px;   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.ctgrs-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container img {
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
}


.ctgrs-container h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.ctgrs-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


.ctgrs-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #727272;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease;
}

/*----------Recent Projects----------*/

#recent-container {
    width: 950px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: ;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.thmbnl-recent {
    padding: 20px 13px 0px 13px;
    width: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.thmbnl-recent h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#recent-title {
    font-family: "calibri light";
    text-align: center;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.thmbnl-recent:hover {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.thmbnl-recent:active {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}


/*--------SLIDE IMAGE---------*/

#gallery-container {
    margin: 75px 0px 45px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
}

#slide-section {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;

}

#gallery-container h1{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

#imgrow {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
      <div id="nav-container">
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
        <a href="posters+flyers.html">Posters & Flyers</a>
        <a id="web" href="#">Website Design</a>

      </div>
  </div>
        <div id='webdsn-drop'>
            <div id="webdsn-content">
                <h2 id="webname">WEBSITE DESIGN</h2>
            </div>
        </div>  


  <div id="banner-container">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM<br>SAMPLE<h1> 
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Sample Lorem Ipsum Sample</h2>
  </div>

 <div id="thmbnl-container">  

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/workspace-banners_23-2147509206.jpg">
      <h1>Web Design</h1>
    </a> 
  </div>


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="posters+flyers.html">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/blue-company-poster_23-2147493194.jpg">
      <h1>Posters & Flyers</h1>
    </a>  
  </div> 


   <div class="ctgrs-container">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wave-business-card-design_1017-4370.jpg">
      <h1>Business Cards</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  <div class="ctgrs-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-logo-template_23-2147490980.jpg">
      <h1>Logo Design</h1>
     </a> 
  </div>

  </div> 

  <h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>
  <div id="recent">
    <div id="recent-container">
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="thmbnl-recent">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes im trying to get the drop down to appear when hovering on website design aka #web

Comment: Yes thank you that worked however there is one more thing that i could never get to work even on ther versions. When i try to explore the slide down div it disappears and since im new to jquery/js i cant get it to work with if else statements

Comment: Also, have I incorrectly linked my javascript cuz its still doesnt work but works in your snippet

Comment: yeah you can copy the code of my snippet. and if you think my answer resolve your question, you should mark it with the green tick.

then, for the other problem you say, you should define how you want your menu to work. you want it to appear when you hover on Website Design, and then you have to think when you want it to disappear.